# hive table transpose operation using sql

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to transpose table using hive QL
This is the souce table below

```
___________________________________________
subject|roll_1|roll_2|roll_3|roll_4|roll_5|
___________________________________________
MATHS  |80    | 90   |   78 |   95 |    68|
___________________________________________
ENGLISH|78    | 78   | 67   |75    |54    |
```

and i want answer in the format as shown in the table below

```
subject|MATHS|ENGLISH|
______________________
roll_1 |80   |78     |
______________________
roll_2 |90   |78     |
______________________
roll_3 |78   | 67    |
______________________
roll_4 |95   |75     |
______________________
roll_5 |68   |54     |
```

please help me to resove this

Comment: which version of hive did you use?

Comment: i am using hive 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I can get to making it generic,as new columns are added,you only have to make changes in ***CONCAT()*** inside ***map()***:

```
select pos1+1 AS rollnum,mat,eng from(
  select collect_list(a.group_map['MATHS']) as MATHS,
         collect_list(a.group_map['ENGLISH']) as ENGLISH,
         from ( select map(SUBJECT,CONCAT(ROLL1,',',ROLL2,',',ROLL3,',',ROLL4,',',
                                                   ROLL5,',',ROLL6)) as group_map
                                                    from db_name.tbl_name) a) b
         lateral view posexplode(split(b.MATHS[0],',')) MATHS AS pos1,mat
         lateral view posexplode(split(b.ENGLISH[0],',')) ENGLISH AS pos2,eng

         WHERE pos1=pos2
```

Though this might affect efficiency somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the SQL to get the desired output.

```
select 'roll_1' as subject,sum(case when subject='MATHS' then roll_1 else 0 end) maths,sum(case when subject='ENGLISH' then roll_1 else 0 end) english from your_table_2
union all
select 'roll_2' as subject,sum(case when subject='MATHS' then roll_2 else 0 end) maths,sum(case when subject='ENGLISH' then roll_2 else 0 end) english from your_table_2
union all
select 'roll_3' as subject,sum(case when subject='MATHS' then roll_3 else 0 end) maths,sum(case when subject='ENGLISH' then roll_3 else 0 end) english from your_table_2
union all
select 'roll_4' as subject,sum(case when subject='MATHS' then roll_4 else 0 end) maths,sum(case when subject='ENGLISH' then roll_4 else 0 end) english from your_table_2
union all
select 'roll_5' as subject,sum(case when subject='MATHS' then roll_5 else 0 end) maths,sum(case when subject='ENGLISH' then roll_5 else 0 end) english from your_table_2
```

Comment: can you please give some generic solution. In this case it is ok to have this solution but what will be the scenario when i have one lac students then this solution might not useful

Comment: The data that you provided is represented the bad data model, because why you want to add one extra column instead of a new row.

Comment: the other solution can be is, you have to use the concept of data mining and ETL then your data will easly in tabular form.

Comment: please provide some optimized solution

Comment: No idea about other solution. I think you are looking something dynamic. Sorry :)

Comment: can we do it by using map_agg(), map() , group_map(), to_map() or collect_list() function